# Running appium programatically in mac terminal using Java

Tags: ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I want to start appium server programatically in mac using Java.

Can any one help me how to write the code to start appium.

Thanks..

Comment: which version of appium u r using

Comment: Appium Version - 1.5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch appium server programmatically with below piece of code.

```
appium = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .usingPort(4723).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1"));
appium.start();
```

If you want to launch from terminal you can run below command

```
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
```

If you want to specify the simulator and app details etc you can run below command.

```
node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --full-reset 
--device-name "iPhone 6" 
--platform-name iOS 
--platform-version "8.3" 
--app "/My.app"
--browser-name iOS
```

For this the node executable should be added to the path.

For starting appium 1.5.3 go through below link.

[starting appium 1.5.3 programmatically](http://www.rightqa.com/start-stop-appium-server-programmatically-using-java-mac-osx/)

Comment: Hi Sai,

"appium = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .usingPort(4723).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1"));
appium.start();"

If i wrote the above code, before execution i need to start "appium" in terminal explicitly. I don't want to do it explicitly.

Comment: No need appium.start(); this step will start the appium

Comment: I'm getting the following exception ::: 
io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException: The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js executable: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node Arguments: [/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/lib/appium.js, --port, 4723, --address, 0.0.0.0, --log, /Applications/AppiumLogs/log.txt] 

 at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.start(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:155)
 at com.kirusa.instavoice.util.AppiumController.appiumSetU

Comment: can u check node.js file path

Comment: is node installed and added to the path

Comment: Yes it is installed

In terminal i executed cmd "which node"

/usr/local/bin/node

Comment: I am sorry this is not for appium 1.5.3 it is for appium 1.6.0

Comment: I'm getting error while initializing ios driver after starting Appium at line

`iosDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'KirusaTestings-Mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.230.123', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
 at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.exe`

Comment: what are the desired capabilities u have given

Comment: `capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "IOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "tester's iPhone");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "e***********************8");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/testing/Desktop/test.app");
capabilities.setCapability("locationContextEnabled", false);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);`

Answer (score 0):

This line will start appium:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("appium");
```

Bonus - The next loop will wait until there will be a message from the executed command

(Please note that It doesn't check the output itself, it just waits until there is one - it works great for me)

```
while ((stdInput.readLine()) == null) {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

After this you can continue with running the project knowing that the Appium server has started

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
        AppiumDriverLocalService appiumServer = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .usingPort(4723).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1"));
    appiumServer.start();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has a few answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.